# Section symbol in table of contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

I'd like sections in the table of contents to have not only the number, but also the symbol § before them. How can I make it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one option using the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\addtolength\cftsecnumwidth{0.7em} 
\renewcommand\cftsecpresnum{\S}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section One}
\section{Test Section Two}
\section{Test Section Three}
\section{Test Section Fout}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: tocloft appears to clash with titlesec, is it possible to achieve the same style with titletoc?

Answer (score 8):

Sections are special in the `article` document class and treated differently from subsections and lower-level sectional units in the ToC. As such, a patch (using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) of `\l@section` to insert `§` is sufficient:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}% <cmd>
  {#1}% <search>
  {\S#1}% <replace>
  {}{}% <search><replace>
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

The patch inserts `\S` before the first argument (`#1`) of `\l@section`. The first argument contains the number and name of the section.

---

For the `report` document class, the following patch does something similar, noting that sections at level `1`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}% <cmd>
  {#4}% <search>
  {\ifnum#1=1\S\fi#4}% <replace>
  {}{}% <search><replace>
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm using the report class for a small book and this patch doesn't work with it. Am I using sectioning wrong?