# Add a symbol before section number in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to highlight some selected sections in the Table of Contents with a symbol before the section number, something like:

`! 1.1 First section`,

and I would like the section numbers to be still allignated, with the exclamation mark on the left of them.

Do you know how can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the meantime welcome in the TeX.SE. I think that your question it is a duplicate of this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102844/section-symbol-in-table-of-contents

Comment: Thank you! In that question the author wants to apply the same symbol to all sections, while I would like to apply a symbol to a list of sections, but not to all of them.

Comment: Carlo, I am a low user especially in the English language. Excuse me....My native speaker it is Italian Language. Then I vote up your question.

Comment: Should the symbol also appear in the printed heading and/or page header, or just in the table of contents?

Comment: @Lupino I would prefer just the table of content, but I can settle if it is too difficult!

Comment: @Lupino do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Carlo i do, but unfortunately, it's not that easy. Do you only need one symbol (e.g., exclamation point), or are there different symbols that should be displayed?

Comment: @Lupino I don't need it anymore since submission date has passed, but maybe you could post the answer for future convenience of other users.. I was asking for just a symbol.