# How to improve the following way to add the section symbol before only section numbers in contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, section-titles

First a MWS and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\makeatletter
\let\OldNumberline=\numberline
\RenewDocumentCommand{\numberline}{m}{%
\OldNumberline{\S{}#1.}%add dot before title numbers in contents
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Models}
\section*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Preface}
\section{A Linear Model}
\subsection{Definitions}


\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, I add the dot after title numbers and the section symbol before title numbers in contents. **Then how to improve it to add section symbol before only section numbers and to add the dot after *all* title numbers at the same time?** Note, I don't want to invoke `tocloft`.

Maybe the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102847/140814) could give some help, but I don't know how to get it here.

Comment: If you don't want to use an additional package, you have to redefine at least `\l@section` not only to add the § and the dot, but also to change the width reserved for the number. BTW: Do you really want to add the § not before the chapter number (§1 in the example) but the section number (§1.1. in the example)?

Comment: @cabohah Yes. And I hope someone could improve the above codes.